# How to run all cucumber tests with a command ? How to setup pom.xml file for this

Tags: maven, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have a cucumber project at local machine and its copy on git. When I'm running the project on local - the test runs successfully.But when i am using mvn test command in cmd no tests are found.

I am using junit in my pom.xml

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>chromedriverProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit-platform.version>5.3.2</junit-platform.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>


       <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber6-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

RunnerTest.java

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefs"},
        monochrome=true,
        plugin = {"pretty", "html: target/cucumber-reports",
                "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}

)
public class RunnerTest  {

}
```

Test.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import factory.WebDriverFactory;
import pages.HomePage;
import pages.LoginPage;
import pages.RegistrationPage;


public class Test {
   
   static final String exePath = "D:\\Installed Softwares\\chromedriver.exe";
   public static WebDriver driver;


   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      launchbrowser();
      LoginPage page = new LoginPage(driver);
      page.login();

      HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);

      WebElement postsTable = homePage.get_Table_Post_Listing();

      List<WebElement> rowVals = postsTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

      int rowNum = postsTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();
      int colNum = rowVals.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th")).size();

      //Loop through the remaining rows
      for(int i=1; i<rowNum; i++) {
         //Get each row's column values by tag name
         List<WebElement> colVals = rowVals.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
         //Loop through each column
         for(int j=0; j<colNum; j++) {
            //Print the column values to console
            System.out.println(colVals.get(j).getText());
         }
         //Just a separator for each row
         System.out.println("---------------");
      }

      closeBrowser();
   }


   public static void launchbrowser() {
      driver=WebDriverFactory.SeleniumGrid();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      
   }
   
   public static void closeBrowser() {
      driver.quit();
   }

}
```

My project:structure: [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgxks.png)

After mvn test running: [mvn test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDKBq.png)

**Edited pom.xml;**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>chromedriver project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
      <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
      <junit-platform.version>5.3.2</junit-platform.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.20</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>6.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>6.11.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
          <version>6.11.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
          <version>5.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.7</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.13.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
          <version>4.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>4.6.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.6.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber6-adapter -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
          <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
          <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.4</version>
      </dependency>


     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
          <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
          <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>


<!--        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.14.3</version>
      </dependency>
      &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng &ndash;&gt;
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
          <version>7.10.1</version>
      </dependency>-->


  </dependencies>

  <build>

      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.6.0</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <includes>
                      <include>**/RunnerTest.java</include>
                  </includes>
                  <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.22.0</version>
              <configuration>
                  <argLine>
                      – illegal-access=permit
                  </argLine>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your POM is too big to be quickly understood. Please start over with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved my problem using maven 3.6.0 version and also I downgrade junit versions 6.11.0

Answer (score 0):

When glanced over your implementation I see that you are missing the `@SuiteClasses` annotation on your test class. Can you try adding the `org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses` annotation on your test class like

```
@SuiteClasses({RunnerTest.class})
public class Test{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved my problem using maven 3.6.0 version and also I downgrade junit versions 6.11.0